# Can gravitational acceleration change with position?

Tags: experimental-physics, acceleration

My class conducted 2 experiments.

[image: ex1]

[image: ex2]

Basically, Experiment 1 has the 2nd photo-gate move 10 cm to the right after every test. Experiment 2 has both move 10 cm right every test.

But the acceleration for Experiment 1 was around 55, and for experiment 2 was around 80-90.

The explanation I'm going for now is that the line protruding from the vertical line was on a higher altitude for experiment 1 than experiment 2, but I don't think our teacher would be that sloppy.

Data as requested:

pg stands for photogate

Experiment 1:

```
|dist a-b|Speed at pgb     |Time from pga to pgb    |
|10cm    |81.97cm/s        |0.153s                  |
|20cm    |94.34cm/s        |0.300s                  |
|30cm    |98.04cm/s        |0.412s                  |
|40cm    |102.04cm/s       |0.558s                  |
|50cm    |111.11cm/s       |0.659s                  |  
|60cm    |116.28cm/s       |0.748s                  | 
|70cm    |121.95cm/s       |0.842s                  |
```

Experiment 2:

```
|              |Test 1    |Test 2    |
|Time at pga   |0.065s    |0.051s    |
|Time at pgb   |0.047s    |0.041s    |
|Time pga-pgb  |0.337s    |0.281s    |
|Speed at pga  |76.92cm/s |98.03cm/s |
|Speed at pgb  |106.38cm/s|121.45cm/s|  
|Acceleration  |87.4cm/s^2|85.2cm/s^2|
```

Why would the accelerations be drastically different?

Comment: How did you calculate the values of acceleration? This is probably what went  wrong.

Comment: Yeah, the car is accelerating the whole time it's on the slope.  If you just measure the time interval between sensors and divide time by distance to calculate speed, the first experiment will give you average speed over the entire range.  The second also gives average speed, of course, but it's over a shorter interval -- an interval *after* the car has accelerated through most of the range in the first experiment.  So the speed will be higher.

Comment: For the 1st experiment, I made a graph that showed the speed at the second photo-gate vs the time it took to get to photo-gate 1 to 2 and used a regression line'sslope asthe acceleration, and for the second experiment, I took the speed at photo-gate B, subtracted the speed at photo-gate A, and divided it by the time it took to get from A-B

Comment: How did you measure speed at photo-gate 2? Did the photo-gates measure speed or time or both? Or did you calculate speed from distance/time? It would be helpful if you could upload a table of **raw data** before processing.

Comment: I now understand what you mean about the line protruding from the vertical line being on a higher altitude. Yes if the ramp was steeper in Expt 2 then the acceleration of the car would be higher. ... Still trying to understand your data :  In Expt 1 why don't you have values for speed at pga? In Expt 2 why is time at pgb less than that at pga, and why doesn't the difference match with your calculation? (0.065-0.047 is not 0.337). And how did you calculate acceleration from data in Expt 1? I estimate a value of about 85cm/s^2 from the distance vs time values, not 55.

Comment: I have re-calculated using your data for distance vs time in Expt 1. I now get an acceleration of 68cm/s^2.  I would still like to understand more about how you calculated the values in both Expts.

Comment: Nevermind, it had to do with the heights.